# What is the nature of the normality assumption in models for longitudinal data?

Tags: normal-distribution, assumptions, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I'm working on a longitudinal dataset to which I've been fitting non-linear mixed effects model in R. Regarding normality, I have a few questions:

1. Can I assume that a longitudinal data is normally distributed?
2. Do tests such as the Shapiro test apply to longitudinal data?
3. Is normality a strict requirement for mixed effects models?

Comment: WOW!
The questions and their given answers are very important for my study!
A lot thanks!❤

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. There is nothing in the longitudinal nature of longitudinal data that necessitates it is normal.  For example, there are longitudinal Bernoulli data (e.g., whether a child is out sick for every day of the school year).  Even if data were continuous, there is nothing about that which necessitates the data be normal.
2. The [Shapiro-Wilk test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapiro%E2%80%93Wilk_test) assumes the data tested are iid (i.e., independent).  That assumption would be violated for longitudinal data.
3. I'm not sure what it means for normality to be a "strict requirement" of a model.  However, linear mixed effects models typically assume normality in two senses:

   - First, they assume the residuals are normally distributed (really the [errors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errors_and_residuals_in_statistics), but that's more nuanced than you probably need to worry about).  This isn't really different from non-mixed linear models.  As with simpler models, if the deviations from normality are smaller, and/or you have more data, the violation of this assumption is less of a big deal.
   - Second, they tend to assume the random effects are normally distributed (although I believe it is possible to relax this and use the $t$ distribution for a more robust option).  Again, the idea isn't that *your sample* is normally distributed, but that the population from which the random effects were drawn was normal.  And again, violations of this assumption are less bad if you have more units and/or the deviations were minor.

Comment: I guess my other question is how do you test for normality in a longitudinal dataset?

Comment: @John, you're welcome. "Normality" in what sense, the normality of the random effects distribution or of the residuals? You should be able to get a vector of either from your model, and then you could do a qq-plot or whatever you like.

Comment: For anyone interested, see https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v056i05 for the R package ('HLMDiag') and a guide on testing the residuals from multilevel data for normality and the like.

It gives you the vectors @gung noted above.